# Run function after 2 sec delay in nodejs

Tags: node.js

This is a simple node js hander in cloud function that is getting called . It is calling another function redisApiCacheRemove as below . I want to call this function after 2 sec of delay , can  do it . Something like , wait for 2 sec and then run that function redisApiCacheRemove

```
            exports.drm = (request, response) => {
            
             const pubsubmessage = Buffer.from(request.body.message.data, 'base64').toString();
               console.log('message received >>' + pubsubmessage);
               const pubsubMessage = JSON.parse(pubsubmessage);
               console.log(pubsubMessage.entity.id);
               redisApiCacheRemove(pubsubMessage.entity.id, pubsubMessage.entity.event);
               return response.status(200).send();
            ;
```

Comment: Do you know how to use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) like this

```js
const delay = 2000 // In milliseconds
setTimeout(() => {
  // The code you want to execute after 2 seconds goes here
}, delay)
```

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout) also returns timeoutID that you can use to [clear the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearTimeout) if you want to cancel the timeout before it happens, e.g

```js
const delay = 2000 // In milliseconds
const timeoutID = setTimeout(() => {
  // The code you want to execute after 2 seconds goes here
}, delay)

clearTimeout(timeoutID) // Will cancel the timeout above
```